# Discover abnormal value from time-series product sales data

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am not sure whether this is more a statistics than pandas question. But here is my problem:

I have a dataset of retail transactions from N products for the period a year. Three columns of data: Col1 – Product_ID, Col2 – TransactionTime, and Col3 – TransactionPrice. I am tasked to separate two type of transactions:

a)  Transactions took place during promotion period, meaning the price is “significantly” lower than the regular price for a while (could be a day, a weekend, or few days) then comes back to regular price.

b)  For each product, imagine/draw a regression, where X = TransactionTime, Y = 
TransactionPrice. How to pinpoint the outliers, meaning the transactions that are “significantly” away from the regression line? My gut is to look at the regression residual value, but how to implement in pandas?

Comment: You could try doing K-mean clustering on it. You should put some dummy data also

Comment: Thanks Sahil. K-mean is an great idea. Challenge is my data set contains N products. I guess it makes more sense to do K-means at each product level.

Comment: if you do not have large N then you can try to do k-mean with k=N and see if products are clustered together. There are other anomalies detection algo in scikit-learn like isolation forest. check this out  http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html